# modifying list of characters in python

Tags: python, list, set

I have a program for creating a FASTA file of sequences.

```
input=['ARIMALTHNAEYSDSFTAL','ARIMFLTHNFEYSESFTAL','AHIMNPTENAEYHESFTAL','AHIMNPTENTEYWDSFTAL','AHIMNDTHNFEYHDSFTAL','AHIMNDTNNTEYWESFTAL','ARIMFDTENAEYHDSFTAL','AHIMADTNNTEYWDSFTAL','ARIMFLTENTEYHESFTAL']

l = len(input[0])

my_residues = [set() for _ in xrange(l)]
for h in input: 
    for i, x in enumerate(h): 
        my_residues[i].add(x)

my_residues = [list(x) for x in my_residues]
print my_residues
```

This will give output like this

```
[['A'], ['H', 'R'], ['I'], ['M'], ['A', 'N', 'F'], ['P', 'L', 'D'], ['T'], ['H', 'E', 'N'], ['N'], ['A', 'T', 'F'], ['E'], ['Y'], ['H', 'S', 'W'], ['E', 'D'], ['S'], ['F'], ['T'], ['A'], ['L']]
```

but I want the output in such a way that all amino acid residues are there in a set if it contains more than one residue.
So the output should look like:

```
[['A'], ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y'], ['I'], ['M'], ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y'], ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y'], ['T'], ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y'],......  ['F'], ['T'], ['A'], ['L']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to track all amino acid residues when building `my_residues`, then when you loop again to create lists, replace the set with the list of all possible amino acid residues if the length is not 1:

```
import string
all_residues = sorted(set(string.ascii_uppercase) - set('BJOUXZ'))

my_residues=[set() for _ in xrange(len(input[0]))]
for h in input: 
    for i, x in enumerate(h): 
        my_residues[i].add(x)

my_residues=[list(x) if len(x) == 1 else all_residues for x in my_residues]
print my_residues
```

This prints:

```
[['A'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y'], ['I'], ['M'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y'], ['T'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y'], ['N'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y'], ['E'], ['Y'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y'], ['S'], ['F'], ['T'], ['A'], ['L']]
```

Comment: its not giving full residues

Comment: @user2151414: You'll have to enlighten me on how to obtain full residues then; your input sample contains no `C`, for instance. Is it just a list we can hardcode?

Comment: many residues will be absent in the input, but in the output every residues should be there if that position is a variable one

Comment: I have 0 bioinformatics knowledge. Is it enough to define `all_residues = ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y']` at the start of the script?

Comment: sorry, yes All alphabets except 'BJOUXZ' are the amino acid residues

Comment: @user2151414: There you go; I opted to define `all_residues` as *all capital letters minus `BJOUXZ`.

Comment: A more concise and readable way could be `all_residues = list('ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY'‌)`

Comment: @grep: sure, but I had fun building the other definition. :-)